# How to create wifihotspot in ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: android, wireshark

I am using ubuntu 10.04 LTS in my lenovo laptop and have a android ICS device.

I want to create a wifi-hotspot in ubuntu, which I can later use for connecting android device. I need this setup for capturing the packets from android device and later analysing them using wireshark in my ubuntu.

I tried to create a new hotspot using "Create a new wireless Network" wizard from network manager applet, but for some reason the following happens.

- It breaks the existing internet connection(either the WLAN, or
  ethernet)
- Its not visible in the list of available WIFI hotspots in
  the android device.

My Chipset information

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:03.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset MEI Controller (rev 07)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82567LF Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation ICH9M/M-E SATA AHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection
15:00.0 CardBus bridge: Ricoh Co Ltd RL5c476 II (rev ba)
15:00.1 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 04)
15:00.2 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 21)
15:00.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C843 MMC Host Controller (rev ff)
15:00.4 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 11)
15:00.5 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 11)
```

Supported interface modes:

```
 * IBSS
 * managed
 * monitor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the network icon and select edit connections.

Go to the wireless tab and click the Add button.

Enter an SSID and choose the ad-hoc mode.

Go to the IPv4 tab and choose "Shared to other computers" method

Go to the IPv6 tab and choose "Ignore"

Deselect the "Connect automatically" check mark.

Click Save.

Then when you are connected through an ethernet cable connection, you can click on network icon, go to "Connect to a hidden wireless network, choose the new network and click connect.

From the android side, you need to enable ad-hoc network compatibility. This is not the right forum to discuss that but you could check [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22131/enabling-adhoc-networking-on-ics-to-connect-to-adhoc-devices)

Comment: Android does not have access to adhoc networks unless rooted. I can't change my laptop connection to 'Infrastructure' from 'Adhoc' since my card doesn't support it. So sadly I still can't connect it. Isn't there any alternative.